# Render rich text in MVC View?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an asp.net MVC application, and I am using rich text in order to store rich text inside my database.

While fetching the rich text from the database and displaying it on the Details page, I no longer see the formatted data. Rather I see the the plain html *(for example < p>< b>< strong>rich text sample< /strong>< /b>< /p>)*.
How can I display rich text as it is formatted and not as plain html using an Html text helper like Html.TextArea?

```
[AllowHtml]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

I have tried setting my View for the Description like this instead of `DisplayFor`, but it still doesn't work:

```
<dd>
    @Model.Description
    @*@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)*@
</dd>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `@Html.Raw(Model.Description)` instead of `@Model.Description`

Comment: I wish i can give you 100 likes for this answer.

Really saved my day.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can use

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Description)
```

I personally don't like it because you can't do anything with it in terms of Display/Editor templates.  If you plan on using any templates, then I would highly recommend using `MvcHtmlString` as the type for your model:

```
public MvcHtmlString Description { get; set; }
```

Now you can:

```
<dd>
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
</dd>
```

And if needed override the template:

[MvcHtmlString.cshtml]

```
<dd>
   @model
</dd>
```